# Are tag posts really "deleted"?

Tags: support, bug, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

I've started writing tag wiki's, but I'm getting this:

[image]

That's the only thing on the page. The link is fine: `http://opensource.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/70`

I haven't had any problem editing normal main site and meta questions and answers, I've been able to review in Suggested Edits, including approving and rejecting tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts.

So, what's happening here?

Comment: Your edits *are* getting through - there's an edit pending on that tag (which nobody but the CMs can review yet)

Comment: It's actually doing that for all tags that I try to add to. That's the issue. Even for the tags that no one should touch (they already have wikis that I added and approved). :/

Comment: Well your edits aren't just getting lost, fortunately. When the CMs get round to it, they'll be reviewed and added.

Comment: Perhaps, but it looks like a bug. I can't edit anything now... :(

Comment: @Gilles are you sure this is fit for a support tag? I feel like this could be a bug in the making as well.